# Play java mysql application disconnects after long idle time (may be after 8 hours)

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, database-connection

I have created an application using **Play Java Framework**. I am using **MySQL** database.

**conf/application.conf:**

```
JDBC_DRIVER = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/<database_name>"
USER = root
PASS = "root"
```

My Play framework application goes down after hours of idle time. So, I have to restart the application and then it starts working.

*How to re-connect the mysql database connection after a long idle time.*

When I try to login into the application after it goes into idle time. It throws **error** - `No operations allowed after connection closed`.

Any help?

Comment: Maybe a shot in the dark, but while it's idle, couldn't you make a while loop that sleeps for 1 hour for example, and makes a "select 1" to the database just to keep the connection on?

Comment: @Elsendion: I was thinking the same (lol). But it is not a good practice to do  . Anything else?

Comment: Check this one. That static class looks good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196739/how-to-keep-connection-alive-in-java

Comment: @Elsendion: Above SO link said that connect, if connection goes. This functionality is already in code.

Answer (score 1):

The default connection pool in play i think is managed by HikariCP. It may be of help for you to look at parameters in Hikari to see if the timeout/idle timeout settings (and combinations ther-of) help .

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

I am assuming here you are not using boneCP , whose setting parameters and defaults are slightly different. http://www.jolbox.com/

Comment: Don't know about HikariCP. I am using **"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.28"** library.

Comment: I got that is HikariCP. HikariCP is default in play framework higher than version 2.4.* but I am using 2.3.2. So, here BoneCP is default and it seems that BoneCP cant' handle connection leak properly. So, I configured HikariCP into my project but I am facing issue. I posted issue here `https://github.com/edulify/play-hikaricp.edulify.com/issues/76`. Please check.